# Passing id parameters to form for load dynamically content in JSF

Tags: forms, jsf, dynamic, datatable

I have as follows:

I have a datatable that prints a historic of mobiles assigned in a determined moment to a list of users, that datatable prints both: assigned and non-assigned, when the administrator wants to edit a particular assignment can change date of assignment, date of expired, number of line, mobile, etc... Well, I make a query for that which only shows mobiles and lines to edit to this user that are NO assigned in that moment for anyone and show the line and terminal that is assign for that user in that moment for if I want to edit some fields relative to his number and terminal and not have to assign another mobile or line because if I do that, line and mobile assigned for that user will not appear for edit and I would be obligated to choose another one.

That's it but I don't know how to load that list of mobiles and list based in the code of assignment to make the filter for my query when it shows up the modal bootstrap form selects retrieve this data according to this code, that's it the code:

**asignacion.jsf**

```
 <h:dataTable columnClasses="codigo, fechaini, fechafin, terminal, usuario, numero, perfil, asignado" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable" value="${listaTerminales.listaAsigMovil_2}" var="o">
                                            <h:column class="hide">
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Codigo"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="${o.codigo}" />
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Fecha Asignación"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="${o.fechaIniStr}"/>                                                        
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Fecha Baja"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="${o.fechaFinStr}"/>                                                        
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Terminal"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:inputHidden class="idTerminal" value="${o.codigoTerminal.codigo}" />
                                                <h:outputText value="${o.codigoTerminal.marca} ${o.codigoTerminal.modelo}"/>                                                       
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Usuario"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="${o.dni.dni}"/>                                                        
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Número"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="${o.codigoNumero.numero}"/>                                                        
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Perfil"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:inputHidden class="idPerfil" value="${o.codigoPerfil.codigo}" />
                                                <h:outputText value="${o.codigoPerfil.descripcion}"/>                                                        
                                            </h:column>
                                            <c:if test="${rol == 'administrador'}">
                                              <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="Asignado"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                  <h:outputText value="${o.asignado}"/>                                                       
                                              </h:column>  
                                                <h:column>
                                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                                   <h:outputText value="Acciones"/>
                                                    </f:facet>
                                                <a data-toggle='modal' href='#asig-movil' class='btn btn-success edit'>
                                                    <i class='icon3-edit icon-white'></i>Editar</a>
                                                </h:column>
                                             </c:if>

                                        </h:dataTable>

  <!-- start modal -->                                                 
                                              <div class="hide fade modal" id="asig-movil">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                                                      <h3>Editar Datos</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                   <h:form class="form-horizontal well" id="form-asig-movil">
                                                    <div class="modal-body">                                                          

                                                        <fieldset>                                                              
                                                            <h:inputHidden id="codigo-form" value="#{terminalesBean.codigoAsig}">                                                                     
                                                            </h:inputHidden>
                                                            <h:inputHidden id="dni-form" value="#{listaTerminales.dni}"></h:inputHidden>
                                                            <h4>Asignado: </h4><h:selectOneRadio layout="lineDirection" id="asignado-form" value="#{listaTerminales.codAsignado}">
                                                                <f:selectItem id="y" itemLabel="SI" itemValue="S"/> 
                                                                <f:selectItem id="n" itemLabel="NO" itemValue="N"/>
                                                            </h:selectOneRadio>                                                                
                                                            <h4>Número de Teléfono: </h4><h:selectOneMenu class="validate[required]" id="numero-form" value="#{listaTerminales.codigoNumero}">
                                                                <f:selectItems var="l"  itemLabel="#{l.numero}" itemValue="#{l.codigo}" value="#{lineasBean.listaLineasNoAsig}" />
                                                                   </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                                            <h4>Terminal: </h4><h:selectOneMenu class="validate[required]" id="terminal-form" value="#{listaTerminales.codigoTerminal}">
                                                                <f:selectItems var="t"  itemLabel="#{t.marca} #{t.modelo}" itemValue="#{t.codigo}" value="#{terminalesBean.terminalesMovilAndAsig}" />
                                                                               </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                                            <h4>Perfil </h4><h:selectOneMenu class="validate[required]" id="perfil-form" value="#{listaTerminales.codigoPerfil}">
                                                                <f:selectItems var="p"  itemLabel="#{p.descripcion}" itemValue="#{p.codigo}" value="#{perfilBean.listaPerfiles}" />
                                                                               </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                                            <h4>Fecha asignación: </h4><h:inputText class="validate[required]" id="fechaini-form" value="#{listaTerminales.fechaAsig}"></h:inputText>
                                                            <h4>Fecha finalización: </h4><h:inputText class="validate[required]" id="fechafin-form" value="#{listaTerminales.fechaFin}"></h:inputText>                            
                                                        </fieldset>   
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</a>
                                                        <p:commandButton id="okInsertar" onclick="if($('#form-asig-movil').validationEngine('validate')===false){return false;}"
                                                                         styleClass="btn btn-primary ok" value="Ok" action="#{listaTerminales.modificar()}"
                                                                         oncomplete="checkCRUD(xhr, status, args)">                                                                
                                                        </p:commandButton>                                                                                                                                                               
                                                      </div> 
                                                    </h:form>

                                                  </div> 

                                              <!-- end modal -->
```

**terminalesBean.java**

```
 package app.bean;

 import app.dao.TerminalFacade; 
 import app.entity.Terminal;
 import java.text.ParseException;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.ejb.EJB;
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
 import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
 import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

 /**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
 @ManagedBean
 @RequestScoped
 @ViewScoped
public class terminalesBean {
@EJB
private TerminalFacade termFac;
private int codigo;
private String fecha_alta;
private Date fecha_alta_date;
private String marca;
private String modelo;
private String configuracion;
private int sn;
private List<Terminal> terminales;
private int codigoAsig;

public int getCodigo(){
    return this.codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo){
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getFechaAlta(){
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");        
    if(fecha_alta_date!=null)
        return formatoFecha.format(fecha_alta_date);
    return null;
}

public void setFechaAlta(String fecha){
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {        
        this.fecha_alta_date = formatoFecha.parse(fecha);
        this.fecha_alta = fecha;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(lineasBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public String getMarca(){
    return this.marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca){
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getModelo(){
    return this.modelo;
}

public void setModelo(String modelo){
    this.modelo = modelo;
}

public String getConfiguracion(){
    return this.configuracion;
}

public void setConfiguracion(String configuracion){
    this.configuracion = configuracion;
}

public int getSN(){
    return this.sn;
}

public void setSN(int sn){
    this.sn = sn;
}

public void setCodigoAsig(int codigoAsig){
    this.codigoAsig = codigoAsig;
}

public int getCodigoAsig(){
    return this.codigoAsig;
}


public List<Terminal> getTerminales(){
    terminales = (List<Terminal>)termFac.findAll();
    return this.terminales;
}

public List<Terminal> getTerminalesFijoAndAsig(){
    terminales = (List<Terminal>)termFac.findByFijoAndAsig(this.codigoAsig);
    return this.terminales;
}

public List<Terminal> getTerminalesMovilAndAsig(){
    terminales = (List<Terminal>)termFac.findByMovilAndAsig(this.codigoAsig);
    return this.terminales;
}

public void setTerminales(List<Terminal> terminales){
    this.terminales = terminales;
}

public void borrar(){
    Terminal t = new Terminal();
    t = termFac.find(codigo);
    termFac.delete(t);
}

public void insert(){
    Terminal t;
    t =(Terminal)termFac.findbysn(sn);
    if(t == null && this.sn != 0){
        t = new Terminal();
        //t.setCodigo(codigo);                 
        t.setFechaAlta(new Date());
        t.setConfiguracion(configuracion);
        t.setMarca(marca);
        t.setModelo(modelo);
        t.setSn(sn);
        termFac.insert(t);
    }
    else{
        t.setConfiguracion(configuracion);
        t.setMarca(marca);
        t.setModelo(modelo);
        t.setSn(sn);
        termFac.edit(t);
    }
    RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("codigo", t.getCodigo());
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("fecha_alta", t.getFechaAltaStr());        
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("marca", t.getMarca());
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("modelo", t.getModelo());
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("configuracion", t.getConfiguracion());
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("sn", t.getSn());
}
public terminalesBean() {
}
```

}

What I want is pass the ${o.codigo} parameter to method setCodigAsig() for then make the filter in method getTerminalesMovilAndAsig() and in the modal load load the content with ids "numero-form" and "terminal-form", how can I do this when click Edit in each row of the datatable and load modal form of this content dynamically according with this code?

Regards!

Comment: Not sure if this could help you, but take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622281/how-to-transfer-parameter-from-managedbean-to-a-jsf-page/16631728#16631728

Comment: SSCCE please! I'm not reading all that markup just to know it's a list. You could make the same question with a bean and only one field!